In Azure Dev Ops, given a branch name, how I do I get the corresponding Pull Request (if one exists)
In Azure Dev Ops, given a branch name, how I do I get the corresponding Pull Request (if one exists).
I have a local branch named FooBranch which I've pushed to the remote repo BarRepo which lives in Azure DevOps. I created a Pull Request in the BarRepo repo from the branch FooBranch.
The is the branch's Url
https://{org}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_git/BarRepo?version=GBFooBranch
The PR url looks like this
https://{org}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_git/BarRepo/pullrequest/{prID}
where {prID} is an 8-digit number.
Given the branch BarRepo how do I determine {prID}? I would like to do this in a PowerShell script if possible. Maybe thru the Azure CLI. Or via an HTTP req.

I know not all branches will have an associated PR. Can a branch be in several PRs?


I know not all branches will have an associated PR. Can a branch be in several PRs?

Yes, a branch can be linked to multiple PRs if it's used as the source for different target branches or if multiple PRs are created from it. For example, a feature branch might have PRs for both the development and release branches, each with a different PR ID but sharing the same source branch.

Given the branch BarRepo how do I determine {prID}? I would like to do this in a PowerShell script if possible. Maybe the Azure CLI. Or via an HTTP req.


Using Azure CLI az repos pr list sample PowerShell task:

steps:
  - powershell:  |
      $organization = ""
      $project = ""
      $repositoryName= ""
      $sourcebranch = ""     

      $prs = az repos pr list --organization https://dev.azure.com/$organization --project $project --repository $repositoryName --source-branch $sourcebranch --output json

      # Parse the JSON response
      $prsJson = $prs | ConvertFrom-Json

      # Check if any PRs are found
      if ($prsJson.Count -eq 0) {
          Write-Output "No Pull Requests found for branch: $sourcebranch"
      } else {
          # Get all PR IDs
          $prIds = $prsJson.pullRequestId
          Write-Output "Pull Request IDs: $prIds"
      }
    displayName: 'az repos pr list'
    env:
      AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)


Test result:


Using REST API Pull Requests - Get Pull Requests sample PowerShell task:

steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'REST API'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        # Set variables
        $organization = ""
        $project = ""
        $repositoryName= ""
        $sourcebranch = ""
        
        # Create the API URL
        $apiUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repositoryName/pullrequests?searchCriteria.sourceRefName=refs/heads/$sourcebranch&api-version=7.1-preview.1"
        
        # Make the HTTP GET request
        $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"} 
        
        # Check if any PRs are found
        if ($response.value.Count -eq 0) {
            Write-Output "No Pull Requests found for branch: $sourcebranch"
        } else {
            # Get all PR IDs
            $prIds = $response.value.pullRequestId
            Write-Output "Pull Request IDs: $prIds"
        }

Test result:


You can use the az repos pr list command to list pull requests and filter results by both source and target branch (among others), if needed:
az repos pr list [--creator]
                 [--detect {false, true}]
                 [--include-links]
                 [--org]
                 [--project]
                 [--repository]
                 [--reviewer]
                 [--skip]
                 [--source-branch]
                 [--status {abandoned, active, all, completed}]
                 [--target-branch]
                 [--top]

Sample YAML pipeline:
trigger: none

steps:
  - checkout: none
  - script: >-
      az repos pr list 
        --organization $(System.CollectionUri) 
        --project $(System.TeamProject) 
        --repository dummy 
        --status active 
        --source-branch foo 
        --output json
    displayName: 'List PRs'
    env:
      AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)

Sample response:
[
  {
    "artifactId": null,
    "autoCompleteSetBy": null,
    "closedBy": null,
    "closedDate": null,
    "codeReviewId": 56,
    "commits": null,
    "completionOptions": null,
    "completionQueueTime": null,
    "createdBy": {
      "descriptor": "aad.xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "directoryAlias": null,
      "displayName": "Bruce Wayne",
      "id": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
      "imageUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/brucewayne/_api/_common/identityImage?id=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
      "inactive": null,
      "isAadIdentity": null,
      "isContainer": null,
      "isDeletedInOrigin": null,
      "profileUrl": null,
      "uniqueName": "brucewayne@somemail.com",
      "url": "https://spsprodeus21.vssps.visualstudio.com/bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb/_apis/Identities/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
    },
    "creationDate": "2024-07-17T14:22:20.079357+00:00",
    "description": "Dummy PR",
    "forkSource": null,
    "isDraft": false,
    "labels": null,
    "lastMergeCommit": {
      "author": null,
      "changeCounts": null,
      "changes": null,
      "comment": null,
      "commentTruncated": null,
      "commitId": "ccccccccccccccccccccccc",
      "committer": null,
      "parents": null,
      "push": null,
      "remoteUrl": null,
      "statuses": null,
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/brucewayne/ddddddddddddddddd/_apis/git/repositories/eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee/commits/ccccccccccccccccccccccc",
      "workItems": null
    },
    "lastMergeSourceCommit": {
      "author": null,
      "changeCounts": null,
      "changes": null,
      "comment": null,
      "commentTruncated": null,
      "commitId": "ffffffffffffffffff",
      "committer": null,
      "parents": null,
      "push": null,
      "remoteUrl": null,
      "statuses": null,
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/brucewayne/ddddddddddddddddd/_apis/git/repositories/eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee/commits/ffffffffffffffffff",
      "workItems": null
    },
    "lastMergeTargetCommit": {
      "author": null,
      "changeCounts": null,
      "changes": null,
      "comment": null,
      "commentTruncated": null,
      "commitId": "ggggggggggggg",
      "committer": null,
      "parents": null,
      "push": null,
      "remoteUrl": null,
      "statuses": null,
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/brucewayne/ddddddddddddddddd/_apis/git/repositories/eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee/commits/ggggggggggggg",
      "workItems": null
    },
    "mergeFailureMessage": null,
    "mergeFailureType": null,
    "mergeId": "hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh",
    "mergeOptions": null,
    "mergeStatus": "succeeded",
    "pullRequestId": 56,
    "remoteUrl": null,
    "repository": {
      "defaultBranch": null,
      "id": "eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee",
      "isFork": null,
      "name": "dummy",
      "parentRepository": null,
      "project": {
        "abbreviation": null,
        "defaultTeamImageUrl": null,
        "description": null,
        "id": "ddddddddddddddddd",
        "lastUpdateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "name": "brucewayne",
        "revision": null,
        "state": "unchanged",
        "url": null,
        "visibility": "unchanged"
      },
      "remoteUrl": null,
      "size": null,
      "sshUrl": null,
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/brucewayne/ddddddddddddddddd/_apis/git/repositories/eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee",
      "validRemoteUrls": null
    },
    "reviewers": [],
    "sourceRefName": "refs/heads/foo",
    "status": "active",
    "supportsIterations": true,
    "targetRefName": "refs/heads/main",
    "title": "Dummy PR",
    "url": "https://dev.azure.com/brucewayne/ddddddddddddddddd/_apis/git/repositories/eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee/pullRequests/56",
    "workItemRefs": null
  }
]


Given the branch BarRepo how do I determine {prID}?

Correspondent property in the above response is pullRequestId.
